# make relation for value from array laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table for data:

```
Schema::create('general', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->string('key')->unique();
  $table->longText('value')->nullable();
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

When adding data, I get the following records in the database:

> id: 2 
> key: country 
> value: ["Italy","Germany"]

Countries are now added to me through tags, like this:

```
$form->tags('value', __('Value'))->help('Use key `<b>Enter</b>` to add a new value')
  ->separators([';']);
```

The model has a function that receives and shares all values ​​with the key country:

```
public static function getCountries()
    {
        $country= self::where('key', 'country')->first();

        return explode(',', $country['value']);
    }
```

And then on the blade.php page I display these countries:

```
@foreach(App\Models\General::getCountries() as $country)
  <span>{{ $country }}</span>
@endforeach
```

The task is to attach a picture with a flag to each country.

I create a new model with migration to add a picture:

```
Schema::create('general_flags', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->string('flag_image', 128);
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

My controllers are all done correctly and pictures are added and saved.

The main question is how do I create a relation of each value from the array with the desired flag, any ideas how to do this?

The problem is that I can’t change adding countries, so I have to work with what I have.

Comment: why dont you create a Flag class related 1:1 with Country ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator I have a Flag class, but I don't understand how to make a relationship with a country when countries are listed in an array as tags

Comment: How are you identifying the flags of countries I didn't find any country foreign key in the `general_flags` table.

Comment: @FaizanAli so what's the point if all countries have the same key, or is there a way to define a different key for each country? but how if the id is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make new col in `general_flags` named `country_code` then when save countries_array in `general` save it as associative array `['country_code' => 'country name']`.
Or save image as associative array `['country_code' => 'Image']`.

But, In my opinion you should make table for countries and every country has a flag.